# Why doesn't the `div` predicate work here?

Tags: first-order-logic, z3

```
(declare-fun pdiv (Int Int Int) Bool)
(assert (forall ((x Int) (y Int) (z Int)) (=> (= z (div x y)) (pdiv z x y))))
```

When I check sat, I've got unknown by Z3

Comment: Hurray, we have our first Z3 question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very common for Z3 to return `unknown` instead of `sat` when using quantifiers. Indeed, constraint systems which use `forall`'s (particularly with `Int`s) quickly reach into undecidable territory.

There are two options. First, if you want to extract a model out of your satisfiable constraints, you can in this instance *define* `pdiv` instead of declaring it:

```
(define-fun pdiv ((z Int) (x Int) (y Int)) Bool 
    (= z (div x y))
)
(declare-const z Int)
(declare-const x Int)
(assert (= x 3))
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (= y 3))
(assert (pdiv z x y))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
; sat -- z = 1
```

`define-fun` is just a macro expansion, so the semantics here are a little different from your example -- if you intended `pdiv` to be strictly weaker than `z = div x y`, you will need to encode this differently.

The other option is to keep the quantified version, but instead of checking `sat`, you *negate* the formula and check for `unsat`:

```
(declare-fun pdiv (Int Int Int) Bool)
(assert (forall ((x Int) (y Int) (z Int)) (=> (= z (div x y)) (pdiv z x y))))

(declare-const mygoal Bool)
(assert (= mygoal (pdiv 2 6 3)))
(assert (not mygoal))
(check-sat)
; unsat
```

This second option is used pervasively in program verification, where quantifiers are used all over the place to encode axioms about the programs at hand. For example, this is what happens in [F*.](http://fstar-lang.org/tutorial/book/under_the_hood/uth_smt.html#a-brief-tour-of-f-s-smt-encoding)